# Migrating from tomcat8 to Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat8, weblogic12c

I have a dynamic web project that was converted to a Spring MVC project. i initially created my Spring project using tomcat, but my requirements are now changed to use weblogic 12c instead of tomcat. i tried changing the target runtime to weblogic instead of tomcat to no use. right now my project only has a web.xml as a base configuration, i do understand that weblogic requires another configuration (weblogic.xml) / as to what i have read and understood. if so how do i generate this weblogic.xml? is that all that is required ? please walk me through the process of this migration. this project was made using eclipse IDE.

Comment: This article for migrating a Spring web app may be helpful: [Weblogic Server 12c: Differences from Tomcat when deploying a web application](http://swkb.net/index.php/application-servers/46-app-serversweblogic/169-weblogic-12c-web-app-differences-from-tomcat-deployment). It specifically describes what to put in **weblogic.xml**.

Comment: @skomisa thank you so much for the detailed article.